# Checkboxes control Radio Checked/Unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, radio-button

I have a checkout page with two radio buttons one for 'Register Account' and 'Guest Account' checkout methods.

I want a single checkbox that when it is checked, it checks the **Register Account** radio button and when it isn't checked it checks the **Guest Account** checkout radio button.

Here is my code so far:
http://jsfiddle.net/hQbpZ/160/

HTML:

```
Remember Me for Future Purposes :<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1"/> <br/><br/>

Register Account :<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio"/><br>
Guest Checkout :<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio"/><br>
```

JS:

```
jQuery('#checkbox1').click(function(){
    jQuery('#radio1').attr('checked', true);    
});        

jQuery('#checkbox1').click(function(){       
    jQuery('#radio2').attr('checked', false);  
});
```

I got part of the functionality down but I don't know how to uncheck a radio button when a checkbox is unchecked.

Comment: At the moment, I don't really have he time to dig through anything, but one option is to hide a third radio button and use that as the default. Bit of a Macgyver solution, but it should fix the problem easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
jQuery('#checkbox1').click(function () {
    jQuery('#radio1').prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
    jQuery('#radio2').prop('checked', !$(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Remember Me for Future Purposes :
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" />
<br/>
<br/>Register Account :
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" />
<br>Guest Checkout :
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" />
<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a toggle variable and link the checked attribute to it
http://jsfiddle.net/hQbpZ/163/

```
var registered = false;
jQuery('#checkbox1').click(function(){
     registered = !registered
     jQuery('#radio1').attr('checked', registered); 
     jQuery('#radio2').attr('checked', !registered);  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to manually uncheck radio buttons, simply because they're not meant to be used that way (**[read more](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/13511/why-is-it-impossible-to-deselect-html-radio-inputs)**). The only way to have a radio button uncheck is by creating multiple radio buttons sharing the same `name` tag, meaning your HTML is already correct.

Your JavaScript does need some changes. It is not necessary to bind a function twice to the same event, so you could reduce it to one binding. Inside that binding you check whether the clicked checkbox is now on or off, and depending on that you check one of the two radio buttons, like so:

```
$('#checkbox1').click(function() {
    if($('#checkbox1').prop('checked') === true) {
        $('#radio1').attr('checked', true);
    } else {
        $('#radio2').attr('checked', false);
    }
});
```